# mysql "<" is not valid at this position, expecting an identifier

Tags: mysql

Im trying to import script to xml, but I got this error frequently.

how can I deal with this error?

I've tried check comma, apostrophe but those things couldn't helpful for me.

```
    UPDATE TWB_TALK_USER_READY
   SET TALK_SERIAL_NUMBER = #{TALK_SERIAL_NUMBER}
    
    <if test="DESIGNATED_USER_ID !='' and DESIGNATED_USER_ID != null">
    ,DESIGNATED_USER_ID = #{DESIGNATED_USER_ID}
    </if>
    
 WHERE ASP_CUST_KEY = #{ASP_CUST_KEY}
   AND TALK_USER_KEY = #{TALK_USER_KEY} 
   AND ASP_SENDER_KEY = #{ASP_SENDER_KEY}
```

error message : `You have an error in your SQL syntax; it seems the error is around: '< if test = "DESIGNATED_USER_ID !='' and DESIGNATED_USER_ID != null" >, DESIGN' at line 5`

thanks.

Comment: Are you using `MyBatis`?

Comment: yep, using MyBatis with Spring framework.

Comment: Should not you put the text you set to TALK_SERIAL_NUMBER between quotes ?

Comment: please regraceful for I'm Junior on this tofic, currently I'm trying to migrate oracle to mysql.xml. but this error keep conflicts with me.

Comment: It seems the template substitution is not happening. Look at the database logs to see the actual query being executed. Or use a mock of MySQL in a test and see what's being passed to it.